# Magento 2.x Migration Final Sync 'Delta' Stage when not Migrating from Live Database

Tags: database, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool, delta-migration

In the middle of a Magento 1.6.2 to Magento 2.x migration.
I made a duplicate of the 1.6 store/database and migrated the data from that database to the new one. That was probably about 2 weeks ago after I sorted out all kinds of data migration problems. The duplicate 1.6 database has the tables added by the migration tool. In order to move ahead I would have to update the duplicate 1.6 database with the new data from the live 1.6 store and then do the delta migration to Magento 2. I'm not sure if this is possible. Or do I need to start over and migrate directly from the live site/database? If you have a method for this, please advise. Thanks.